# Left join on date range by group ID

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider this token data set:

```
Data = structure(list(txs = c(-50, -750, -35, -5.96, -61.5, -42.07, 
-142.4, -500, 132, -154.89, -109.51, -2000, -50, -40, -24.98, 
-15.6, -50, -147.72, -20, -6.6, -5, -20, -13.48, -7.25, -54.09, 
-200, -124.11, -30, -50, -30, 400, -10, -0.95, -4.1, -10000, 
30, -1.99, 74.03, -6.95, -2.96, -29, -403.6, -6, -6, 5250, -513.57, 
-300, -10, -500, -20, -6.45, -7.26, -40, -50, -13.14, 321.29, 
-18, 100, -5.5, -25, -59.2, -10.75, -3.2, 270, 65.8, -11.6, -104.78, 
-99.39, 0.1, -50, -80, -50, -371.44, -78, 270, -6.3, 40, -2.5, 
-29.99, -189.48, -400, -0.29, -20, -6.55, -987.37, -1400, -0.49, 
-20, -29.04, -65, -40, -27.5, -17.37, -10, -1092.84, -5.5, -69.93, 
-15.07, -400, -4.8), week = structure(c(1439157600, 1454281200, 
1471212000, 1445205600, 1448233200, 1451862000, 1449442800, 1453676400, 
1460325600, 1460930400, 1445205600, 1454281200, 1460930400, 1444600800, 
1462140000, 1471816800, 1443996000, 1448838000, 1479682800, 1453071600, 
1447023600, 1473631200, 1465768800, 1433109600, 1445205600, 1433714400, 
1466978400, 1441576800, 1459116000, 1451862000, 1436133600, 1440367200, 
1456095600, 1458514800, 1456700400, 1450047600, 1440972000, 1446418800, 
1465164000, 1441576800, 1442181600, 1453071600, 1461535200, 1460930400, 
1438552800, 1464559200, 1447628400, 1434924000, 1437343200, 1436738400, 
1443391200, 1438552800, 1440972000, 1446418800, 1446418800, 1453071600, 
1453071600, 1457305200, 1444600800, 1462140000, 1435528800, 1457305200, 
1437948000, 1440972000, 1437948000, 1433109600, 1461535200, 1453676400, 
1454886000, 1454281200, 1441576800, 1441576800, 1471212000, 1453071600, 
1451862000, 1442786400, 1443391200, 1439762400, 1436133600, 1461535200, 
1442181600, 1468188000, 1442181600, 1453676400, 1466373600, 1443391200, 
1450652400, 1454886000, 1439157600, 1441576800, 1463954400, 1442181600, 
1446418800, 1454886000, 1476050400, 1461535200, 1456700400, 1456700400, 
1435528800, 1456700400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    num_c = c(1219, 1257, 1195, 33, 1105, 1223, 1257, 1317, 486, 
    1227, 477, 1039, 1238, 1008, 1137, 1294, 1070, 596, 1295, 
    1354, 1010, 1294, 1348, 1254, 19, 1185, 24, 1287, 1198, 955, 
    1324, 1293, 1343, 1162, 1272, 972, 972, 179, 1343, 1105, 
    1085, 1020, 947, 1375, 1005, 477, 596, 1198, 928, 1137, 1263, 
    1237, 1054, 1288, 1185, 1115, 1257, 1301, 1294, 1185, 1039, 
    957, 1131, 33, 477, 1258, 477, 1039, 1362, 1246, 596, 1010, 
    972, 1238, 477, 1296, 972, 1148, 1105, 24, 553, 1297, 1288, 
    1223, 789, 1298, 1082, 1353, 1030, 1287, 1203, 1008, 1294, 
    1227, 1298, 1203, 1346, 1010, 19, 1303)), .Names = c("txs", 
"week", "num_c"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

it has three columns:

- one called `num_c`: this is a client number
- one called `week`: this is the date of the Monday of the weeks in which 
                  `num_c` placed an order.
- one called 'txs': balance on account per week and client (num_c)

Now, for every client I would like to use dplyr to expand (join) this data set 
so that I get one row for each week in the range of dates during which
 that client has placed orders.

Moreover, the **new** empty cells (for txs) should be filled with NA's.
The values of txs corresponding to those weeks/clients that are present in the original (no expanded) data set should retain their original values;

I tried:

```
 library(dplyr)
 stretch_Data = Data %>%
                group_by(num_c) %>%
                right_join(seq(min(week), max(week), by = 'week'), by = "week")
```

But I get;

```
Error in seq(min(week), max(week), by = "week") : object 'week' not found
```

which is silly because Data does contain a week column (thank you very much).

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

Thanks to @mt1022 for his solution (comment below). This is quiet clever. But one problem remains: is it possible to include all the colums from Data? --To make my point I've added one: txs-- Then the missing values (**those corresponding to weeks with no purchase**) should be filled by NA's (like in a joint). The cells corresponding to client * week dates for which we had a purchase should just retain their original values.

In essence doing na.omit() on the new (expanded table) should return the original table; like it would on a joint;

Comment: The error is quite obvious. There is no column `week` in `seq(min(week), max(week), by = 'week')`.

Comment: But Data contains a column week; How do you tell dplyr to pull week from Data?

Comment: The two dataframes to be joined should both contain the join column. I would try something like: `Data %>%
    group_by(num_c) %>%
    summarise(week = list(seq(min(week), max(week), by = 'week'))) %>%
    unnest(week)` for your case.

Comment: @mt1022: Thanks! this is quiet clever. But one problem remains: is it possible to include all the colums from Data? --To make my point I've added one-- Then the missing values (those corresponding to weeks with no purchase) should be filled by NA's (like in a joint);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution from @mt1002 with one simple addition to obtain the `txs` column.  I have obtained a single value by `sum(txs)`, where this could also be a single value of the `min(txs)` or `max(txs)` depending on your needs.

```
Data %>% group_by(num_c) %>% 
  summarise(week = list(seq(min(week), max(week), by = 'week')),
            txs = sum(txs)) %>% 
  unnest(week)
```

After the clarification, this is the solution I came up with where there are NA values for weeks there were no orders, in addition to the number of orders per user per week.  You could also join the list of weeks with orders by `num_c` using a left-join including the above query to the df.

```
library(lubridate)
a <- data.frame(week = rep(seq(1,52,1)))
Data %>% 
  group_by(num_c) %>% 
  mutate(week_num = week(week)) %>% 
  group_by(num_c, week_num) %>% 
  summarise(txs = sum(txs),
            number_orders = n()) %>% 
  full_join(a, by = c("week_num"="week")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(week_num)
```

Comment: closer but not there yet. Look at weeks 2015-10-19 and 2015-06-29. For those weeks § num_c = 19,  the values of txs should be -54.09 and -400 (those weeks are  in the Data for that client). But your code returns -454.09 for all weeks (the behavior should be instead to put NA for all weeks except  2015-10-19 and 2015-06-29 which should have their correct, original values)

Comment: Would it be easier to create a df of all weeks within a year, then populate that df with the number of orders per week, and then the sum or NA of txs per week?  I've used lubridate or similar to do this and had good results.

Comment: yes, but it should be done on a per num_c (client) basis. E.g.  populate that df with the number of orders per week *per client*. Like the data set in your answer, for q given client, we do not need to create rows for week outside the time range of *that* client (even if the range of all clients covers many years).